# Computed Getter causes maximum stack size error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement the following logic in Nuxt:

1. Ask user for an ID.
2. Retrieve a URL that is associated with that ID from an external API
3. Store the ID/URL (an appointment) in Vuex
4. Display to the user the rendered URL for their entered ID in an iFrame (retrieved from the Vuex store)

The issue I'm currently stuck with is that the getUrl getter method in the store is called repeatedly until the maximum call stack is exceeded and I can't work out why.  It's only called from the computed function in the page, so this implies that the computed function is also being called repeatedly but, again, I can't figure out why.

In my Vuex store index.js I have:

```
export const state = () => ({
  appointments: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_APPT: (state, appointment) => {
    state.appointments[appointment.id] = appointment.url
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async setAppointment ({ commit, state }, id) {
    try {
      let result = await axios.get('https://externalAPI/' + id, {
        method: 'GET',
        protocol: 'http'
      })
      return commit('SET_APPT', result.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}

export const getters = {
  getUrl: (state, param) => {
    return state.appointments[param]
  }
}
```

In my page component I have:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <section class="container">
            <iframe :src="url"></iframe>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        url: function (){
            let url = this.$store.getters['getUrl'](this.$route.params.id)
            return url;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The setAppointments action is called from a separate component in the page that asks the user for the ID via an onSubmit method:

```
data() {
  return {
    appointment: this.appointment ? { ...this.appointment } : {
                    id: '',
                    url: '',
                },
                error: false
     }
},
methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    if(!this.appointment.id){
      this.error = true;
    }
    else{
      this.error = false;
      this.$store.dispatch("setAppointment", this.appointment.id);                     
      this.$router.push("/search/"+this.appointment.id);             
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show also your 'getUrl' getter? Because I could not see it in the store above. It seems that your pattern should be wrong because you do this.$store.getters['getUrl'](this.$route.params.id) but it is a function call and the getter should not be a function call just a reference. If  I were you, I would create a selectedAppointment state.

Comment: @MátéWiszt In some cases you can pass a parameter to a getting instead of using a secondary filtering value in he store. https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/688#issuecomment-285869557

Comment: Updated with the getter.  What would a selectedAppointment state look like?

Comment: If you want to keep it as a getter, I advise to follow this: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/688#issuecomment-380509722

Comment: I would do it like this: not creating an object of appointments but refactor it like this: SET_APPT: (state, appointment) => {
    state.selectedAppointment = appointment.url
  }. Of course if you want, you can also say in the same mutation that state.appointments[appointment.id] = appointment.url so you will also keep the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what was causing the multiple calls.  However, as advised in the comments, I've now implemented a selectedAppointment object that I keep up-to-date

I've also created a separate mutation for updating the selectedAppointment object as the user requests different URLs so, if a URL has already been retrieved, I can use this mutation to just switch the selected one.

```
SET_APPT: (state, appointment) => {
    state.appointments = state.appointments ? state.appointments : {}
    state.selectedAppointment = appointment.url
    state.appointments = { ...state.appointments, [appointment.appointmentNumber]: appointment.url }
},
SET_SELECTED_APPT: (state, appointment) => {
    state.selectedAppointment = appointment.url
}
```

Then the getUrl getter (changed its name to just url) simply looks like:

```
export const getters = {
  url: (state) => {
    return state.selectedAppointment
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help guys.